# Aliens to the Moon

Tags: algorithms, optimization, efficiency

> $N$ Aliens want to reach their Moon ($D$ meters away), but they can only
>   put on each other, making a vertical chain. Every $Alien(i)$ has an height
>   $X(i)$ and a lenght of their arms $Y(i)$.
>
> When the vertical chain is made we enumerate the Aliens from $1$ to $N$ ( $Alien(1)$ is the alien at the bottom of the chain ).
>
> $Alien(j)$ can reach the Moon $IFF$ $X(1)+X(2)+...+X(j)+Y(j)$ ≥ $D$.
>   After that, $Alien(j)$ jump into the Moon and it cannot be used to make any other chain; the others can make a new chain.
>
> Suppose we have a set $S=${$Alien(1), Alien(2), ... Alien(N)$}, determine the maximum number of Aliens that can be in the Moon after all possible chains.

Is there an intelligent strategy to solve this problem except brute force?

I used a greedy approach to solve this problem:

- First of all every $Alien(i)$ with $X(i)+Y(i)$ ≥ $D$ can reach the Moon everytime, so I can set them at the bottom of the chain
- The remaining Aliens are sorted by $X(i)+Y(i)$ in ascending order from the bottom to the top; the idea is: if the Alien at the top can't reach the Moon, than every Alien under him can't (except the Aliens of the first step)
- Now, from the top to the bottom I keep the Aliens that can reach the Moon in a Priority_Queue where the Alien at the top of the PQ is the bigger in $X(i)$;
  the idea of the Priority_Queue is: a very tall Alien can be used to help his friends to reach the Moon
- If the Alien at the top of the chain can't reach the Moon set the Alien at the top of the PQ at the bottom of the chain. Repeat from step3
- The maximum number of aliens in the Moon is $aliensFirstStep+max(sizePqInStep3)$

But it seems that this approach fails in some examples.

Comment: What is the context you ran across?  What have you tried?  What algorithm paradigms have you considered?  Many users here discourage "problem dumps", where you copy-paste a problem statement and expect someone to solve it for you.  Instead, this site is more suitable if you have a specific question about a specific aspect of the problem or some specific part you are stuck on.  We expect you to make a serious effort to try everything you can think of, and show us in the question what you've tried.

Comment: I'm sorry: question edited! :)

Comment: OK, so you've tried one algorithm design paradigm -- greedy algorithms -- and it didn't seem to work.  So, what else have you tried?  Do you know any other algorithm design paradigms?  If so, what ones do you know?  Have you tried each of them?  We're not here to do your exercises for you -- so your next step should be to review what other paradigms you know, and then try each one, one by one.

Comment: "It seems that this approach fails in some examples"- Could you discuss these examples?